# Save API Response as XML file

Tags: java, api, xml-parsing, rest-assured

I'm actually working on a test project using "REST Assured" in Java :Using a get API to retrive an xml content ( the content type is "application/atom+xml") then update this xml and push it using a post API.
My idea is to save the response body of get API in xml file -> update it -> post it -> delete the xml file
and I'm blocked in the first step to save the response in xml file, I tried many methods but could'nt succeed.

Any solution for this or any other ideas

I tried saving the response  as a String then convert it to XML , but the xml content is too big so I get many errors which fixing it will change the format/content
I also tried using the XMLpath to parse the content that I want to change without saving it to a file but couldnt make it work because I save the response to a string then parse it

Comment: Pls, show your code, we can't help with text.

Comment: So you're saying you probably can't use the regular methods because your XML response doesn't fit into a `String` to hold the response temporarily? If so, to the extend possible, maybe you might be able to obtain a stream from the network response and feed it into a stream-based writer, to never hold much/all of the response in a `String`/memory, and just forward smaller chunks of the response onto disk.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the xml format , I had to use transformer to make it pretty and safe it as xml

```
  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes" );
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(out));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("my-file.xml");
          fw.write( out.toString());
          fw.close();
```